# Text rotated by 90° using only CSS

Tags: css, text-rotation

Is it possible to rotate text by 90° (clockwise or counter-clockwise) using only CSS and compatible with IE6+, Firefox 2 and Opera?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How can I draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser/1080812#1080812)

```
.rot-neg-90 {
  /* rotate -90 deg, not sure if a negative number is supported so I used 270 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  /* IE<9 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

[IE<9 Rotation property for BasicImage filter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: pretty cross browser: >= ie6, >= ff2, and webkit

Answer (score 1):

The BasicImage filter in IE can do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: pretty sure that's not compatible with Firefox 2 or Opera

Comment: The original version of the question only specified IE6 and later.

Comment: @colin.coghill: its still a valid answer, just not a complete answer. On firefox and webkit is easier. Opera is tougher.