# Vertical Text with CSS

Tags: css, text, rotation

Can I rotate text to be shown vertically using CSS in all browsers back to IE6? For example I need 'WORD' rotated 90 deg left so that 'W' is at the bottom and 'D' at the top.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser

Comment: Aha. But that still doesn't include IE6 and its the other way round, I need 'W' at the bottom.

Comment: It states that it is IE5.5+ (that would be IE6), and as far as the other way around, that just involves changing the rotation settings and parameters, the concept is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for IE, try this:

```
#myText {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(VS.85).aspx

I'm sorry, but I can't get to IE right now to test versions, but I'm pretty sure it is supported back to IE6.