# Is is possible to have vertical text orientation in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am asking if it is possible to do something like this:

1

9

8

4

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try something like...

```
.verticaltext{
font: bold 13px Arial;
width: 15px;
writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.rotate {
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```