# Writing in the horizontal, left of the div

Tags: css, html

Basically I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZuUZ/
There I have a div with a gray border, and the left edge of this would like to write vertical "architecture" . How can I do this?

Comment: When you say horizontally, do you actually mean vertically, i.e. rotate the horizontal text 90 degrees clockwise?

Comment: Might be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can rotate text with CSS3](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation).

```
#title {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5ZuUZ/4/).

Comment: this is css3? css3 can not be because it is a customer need that run perfectly well on the smartphone

Comment: @Riderman Depends on the Smartphone. Mobile Safari will render it fine. If compatibility is an issue, you will need to render it as an image.

Comment: You're right!
but your example works very well, I think the solution would be an image even for compatibility reasons.
Any idea how to create a transparent image to accomplish this task?

Comment: @Riderman Type the text into image editing software onto a transparent background, and then rotate the canvas 90° counter-clockwise.