# Browser compatibility in vertical text

Tags: css

I want to below vertical text

[image]

I use:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

but it does not not work in IE 5 nor 6.

Another code I use:

```
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
```

But it does not work in Firefox

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of solutions here in an alternative thread : [How can I draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)