# Vertical Text on a webpage

Tags: html, css, text-rotation

Let me preface by saying I know this question has been asked plenty, but none of the answers worked for me.

Most solutions instruct the use of `transform:rotate(270deg);`, however, this messes with the width as the block is generated in a way that doesn't take into consideration the rotation, making the block wider than desired.

My goal is to get something like the following (in a table):

[image: Desired result]

I have been playing around with a variety of different CSS properties with now luck. [Here is a basic sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/4qwgn/) I have been working with, which demonstrates some of the problems I have been experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the `th` like this:

```
<th>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="vert">Column 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="vert">Col 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="vert">Column Two</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

And add the CSS provided in the Fiddle and you will get the desired result, I hope.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4qwgn/2/)

Answer (score 2):

JSFiddle seems to be down, so I can't see your code -- but perhaps you should include `transform-origin` in addition to the `rotate` transform.  Here's a demo of what I mean: http://jsbin.com/isinoh/2/edit

Comment: If you need support for old browsers, you can use [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) [(demo)](http://raphaeljs.com/text-rotation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `canvas` element in which you can render your text manually. In that case, you will have to adjust the element's width and height manually as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult part here is to combine vertical text with table formatting. Cf. to [How can I draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser) It seems that you may need extra markup at two levels in each header cell, because you need positioning (in order to take the rotated content out of the cells so that their unrotated dimensions don’t mess up table formatting) and table cells don’t behave well when positioned.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
* { line-height: 1.3 }
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#title th
{
    width: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#title th > div {
   position: relative; 
}
#title th > div > div {
   position: absolute; 
   bottom: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
   -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
   transform-origin: 0 100%;
   left: 1.1em;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr id="title">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th><div><div>Column 1</div></div></th>
        <th><div><div>Column 2</div></div></th>
        <th><div><div>Column 3</div></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result won’t be very pretty in many systems, because rotated text is not drawn well due to font rendering issues (hinting fails to help when you are not writing normal horizontal text).