# How to set vertical text from bottom to top in html?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

It is easy to set text from `top to bottom` and there are enough resources to do that.

The problem is with `bottom to top` vertical alignment.

**See the image below**-

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the alignment?

Comment: @putvande I didn't figured out the way to set the bottom to top vertical alignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser ?

Comment: These are dynamically generated texts. So I considered putting each text in a `<td>` tags in a table.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this.

```
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<head>
<style>
div
{
  width:130px;
  height:50px;
  -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<div><h3>Vertical Text</h3></div>
</body>
```

Comment: These are dynamically generated texts. So I considered putting each text in a <td> tags in a table. Any idea ?

Comment: Instead of `div{...}` define a class. Name it anything like `rotate{...}` and then use `<td><div class="rotate">Your Text</div></td>` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Is it necessary to create a class. Can't I simply do: `<div style='font-size:8px;-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);" +"-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);-o-transform:rotate(270deg);>Vertical Text</div>`

Comment: It obviously isn't necessary to create a class! Classes are so that you won't need to repeat those lines of code again and again and your code looks cleaner. But yeah! It would work either way.

Comment: No, it didn't worked. My `itextpdf` in android which converts html to pdf is still displaying it horizontal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41520/discussion-between-ranveer-and-ved-prakash)

Answer (score 0):

```
div {  
    top:90px;   
    position:relative;  
    width:50px;   
    white-space:nowrap; 
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);   
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);   
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);  
    -o-transform:rotate(270deg);   
}
```

Worked well for me.