# CSS GRID vertically align text so it dosn't leave the container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

First im sorry for the sloppy Css im still new to it.
?[Im trying to follow this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UmvC.jpg)But i can't figure a way to make the text align vertically without it leaving the grid header or disappearing.Any tips?
Thnx in advance.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "first-section"
    "second-section"
    "footer";
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#something{
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div id="something">
                    <h1>Someting</h1>
                    <h2>NAME GOES HERE</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="picture">
    
            </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If my *guess* is right though you should know that a transform is **purely visual** and does not affect layout. You will need to search some more on [**vertical text**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rotating it buy -90deg, use

```
#something {
    color:red;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

Try inspecting the #something div. Notice how it is rotated, but the grid doesn't stretch to fill it?

This is because the browser works out how things look in three separate steps:
Layout, Paint and Composite.

When you use a css transform, the browser only redoes the composite step, the layout doesn't change.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. When i use that it dosn't only align it but also goes to the right and rotates it.Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Well, now that you have it laid out correctly, you could add `transform: rotateY(180deg);`