# CrossBrowser Vertical CSS Text

Tags: html, css

I want make CrossBrowser Vertical CSS Text , i have this [code](https://gist.github.com/aiboy/7406727)

but I need the text to rotate like this :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjAER.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it via [`transform: rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) CSS property, for example:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>First</h1>
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <h1>Third</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @mat7777 there is no property, which will work in **all** browsers, but the list of browsers, which support this feature is not bad, you can check it here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d (click "Showing all")