# How can I display English and CJK text sideways using CSS?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, locale, cjk

This is a topic visited by [How can I draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser) 14 years ago, and there doesn't seem to be any clear solutions.

Ideally, I want both the CJK and the latin characters to be vertical with their bottom facing the right side.

`writing-mode: sideways-rl` produces the following output that exactly matches what I want. The only problem is: It's Firefox exclusive and no other browsers support it as of 2023 (https://caniuse.com/?search=sideways)

[image: sideways-rl]

Many people proposed the workaround of using `vertical-rl` then flipping the text using `scale(-1)` or `rotate(180deg)`. This works totally fine for latin characters, but the CJK text will be upside-down.

```css
writing-mode: vertical-rl
transform: rotate(180deg)
```

[image: CJK text upside-down]

I also tried rotating the entire container of horizontal writing -90°, which leads to many alignment and text rendering issues since HTML alignment is computed before `transform`, and workarounds like `margin: -100px; padding: 100px` aren't very elegant and often lead to more issues such as pointer hitbox misalignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intended that CJK characters will remain upright instead of being rotated because of how they can be read in both directions. However, You can force the rotation using [text-orientation: sideways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation#sideways), which is [supported by most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation#browser_compatibility).

(Note that `text-orientation: sideways` rotates the text 90 degrees clockwise, so you still need to keep the `transform: rotate(180deg)` to flip the text.)

```css
.verticalbox {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways;
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="verticalbox">
  Oct 28 星期六
</div>
```

---

Note: Though might not matter in your case, for multiple lines with `lr`, we still need to replace it with `rl` and `rotation(180deg)`, as described in [this W3C article](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/index#other-orientation):

> Note that the result of using this property-value pair with with writing-mode:vertical-lr is different from that seen when using writing-mode:sideways-lr since the text starts at the top of the block and glyphs lie on their right side. Note also that when a line breaks, **lines progress in the opposite direction** to what you would normally want, because lines read later appear to the right of (visually, above) those read earlier.